# Identify ITIN from SSN in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sequence, between

I am trying to return records from a database of unformatted Social Security numbers (ie no dashes). I am looking to pull those that are actually ITINs. Here is the sequence according to the IRS: "The range includes 900-70-0000 through 999-88-9999, 900-90-0000 through 999-92-9999, and 900-94-0000 through 999-99-9999"

Seems simple but I'm getting some misreads e.g. one returned was xxx21xxxx. Could be the humidity here or some undiagnosed illness but I just can't get what I expected. Any help will greatly be appreciated. Below is the syntax for the SQL

```
Select Name, SSN
from Tbl
  where
(Tbl.SSN between '900700000' and '999889999')
or
(Tbl.SSN between '900900000' and '999929999')
or
(Tbl.SSN between '900940000' and '999999999')
```

Comment: Aside from your problem why not just do `between '900700000' and '999999999'` since all values between those numbers will be included in the overlapping ranges.

Answer (score 1):

Regular SSN's don't start with a 9, only ITIN's  start with 9  so  try:

```
select name, ssn from tbl   where substring(ssn,1,1) = '9';
```